# Draw a convex hull in 2D

Tags: convex-analysis

What does the convex hull look like for the points below? is that just these three points connected by lines between these points?

$\text{convexhull}\{(3,2);(2,3);(2.1,2.1)\}$

And can I draw this in Matlab? I tried to do this with the function convex hull but it gives the error: Not enough unique points specified.

Answer (score 1):

It's a triangle, which is convex, so its convex hull is itself...